# Deploying smart contract web3 Invalid RPC response

Tags: javascript, node.js, web3js

I'm trying to deploy a contract on my node server as follows:

```
var escrow = 'pragma solidity ^0.4.4;contract Escrow {address public challenger;address public participant;address public arbiter;function Escrow(address _participant, address _arbiter) {challenger = msg.sender;participant = _participant;arbiter = _arbiter;}function payoutToParticipant() {if(msg.sender == challenger || msg.sender == arbiter) {participant.send(this.balance);}}function refundToChallenger() {if(msg.sender == challenger || msg.sender == arbiter) {challenger.send(this.balance);}}function getBalance() constant returns (uint) {return this.balance;}}';

module.exports.createEscrowContract = function(req, res) {
    //Set variables
    var challenger = '0xE6...';
    var participant = '0x4E...';
    var arbiter = '0xe5C...';

    //Compile contract
    var compiled = solc.compile(escrow);

    console.log(compiled);
    const web3 = new Web3();
    web3.setProvider(new 
    web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/XXXX"));

    //Store bytecode
    var bytecode = compiled.contracts[':Escrow'].bytecode;

    //Store abi
    var abi = JSON.parse(compiled.contracts[':Escrow'].interface);

    var escrowContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);

    //Seems to compile fine.
    console.log(escrowContract);
   
    //Deploy contract
    var deployed = escrowContract.new(participant, arbiter, {
      from: challenger,
      data: bytecode,
      gas: 470000,
      }, (error, contract) => {

           console.log(error); 
           // Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
           console.log(contract);
           //undefined
      });
     

}
```

I've tried several things and read in the documentation but can't seem to find anything! I'm sure I can't be the only person with this issue, I'm using web3@0.20.

Comment: Cross-linking with https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36916/not-able-to-deploy-contract-web3-js-invalid-json-rpc.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues I can spot:

1. You're passing 47,000,000 gas, which is absurdly high. To put it in context, an entire *block* can only use 8,000,000 gas. If you actually used 47 million gas at current gas prices, it would cost over $200 USD. I believe that this would cause your transaction to be rejected before any node attempted to run it.
2. [Infura](https://infura.io), as a public node, can't ever have your private key (in this case, the `challenger`'s private key), so it can't sign a transaction for you. If `challenger` is your account, then you can hold the key and sign the deployment transaction before broadcasting it. If `challenger` is a user of your app, you're better off having the user sign and send the transaction themselves via something like [MetaMask](https://metamask.io).

Comment: Hi smarx, thanks for the replying. I've lowered the gas but unfortunately hasn't helped :/

Comment: As for the second point, I was just following what they were doing here (without really looking at the gas!): https://gist.github.com/bitgord/abf55f9db4fa49333ae165768daef227

Comment: What they're doing makes sense if the node holds their private key (e.g. they're connecting to MetaMask or a local private node like Geth or Parity). But you're trying to do it while connecting to a public node that doesn't have access to any private keys.

Comment: So am I right in thinking that you mean the challenger field must be the private key? Rather than the address?

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, the node signs the transactions (and to do so needs the private keys). On private nodes they can hold the private keys, but you don't want to send the private key to a public node. So would the answer not be to sign this before sending to Infura?

Comment: Right. Yes, the solution (if you're the one with the private key) is to sign the transaction before sending it to Infura. That's what I meant by "If challenger is your account, then you can hold the key and sign it before deployment." I guess "it" was ambiguous there; I meant to refer to the transaction. I'll edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163551/discussion-between-swimmingg-and-smarx).